# extract part of grep line using regex

Tags: grep

I'm using the following command to get java.home path

```
java -XshowSettings:properties -version 2>&1 > /dev/null | grep 'java.home'
```

the command above returns

> ```
> java.home = /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64
> ```

How can I get it to only return "/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64"

Comment: `grep -oP 'java\.home\s*=\s*\K.+'`

Comment: Suggestion of @WiktorStribiżew is nice provided Perl regular expressions are implemented in the `grep`. Otherwise you can use `grep 'java.home' | grep -o '[^ ]*$'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use awk to cut out the last field:

```
java -XshowSettings:properties -version 2>&1 >/dev/null | grep 'java.home' | awk '{print $NF}'
```

Or a little shorter:

```
java -XshowSettings:properties -version 2>&1 | awk '/java.home/ {print $NF}'
```

Comment: I suggest to add `-F ' = '` to work around the problem with spaces in the path.

Comment: Yes, it also works: `... | awk -F ' = ' '/java.home/ {print $2}'`